# Can a custom javascript web application be uploaded and run on ArcGIS online?

Tags: arcgis-online

I'm researching arcgis online and have a subscription account. From what I can make out from the documentation and some experimentation, I've found the following:

- You can create a feature service or tiled map service and have ArcGIS online host it (but not a dynamic map service). You can reference from anywhere using the REST service.
- You can create a "web map" that gives you a viewer and simple widgets, scale bar, zoom, etc. Using the ID of the web map, you can reference anywhere either arcgis online or your own site.
- You can create a "web application" from one of a couple dozen template that gives you a few more options for customization such as popups and even editing widgets. You can run it on ArcGIS online. You can also download the template, customize if desired and run on your server.
- You can upload a reference to a "web application", basically a bit of publicity and add it to your to your gallery. However, the web application only runs on your own webserver.

Question: Can you upload your custom web mapping application to ArcGIS online and have them host it? I'm understanding that this is not possible. Can someone confirm or deny? Thanks!

Comment: Just to update this.. Answer is No, ArcGIS Online cannot host your custom application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you would not be able to; your application would need to be built using the AGSOnline template and built using totally the AGSOnline configuration.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you can't do that.   Definitely would be nice if you could.  The other route would be to purchases a ArcGIS Server license on AWS but as I'm sure you know that is pretty expensive route.  Most people seem to be moving to opensource because Esri doesn't seem to be providing a reasonably priced option in this area.  I feel until they add Geoprocessing and geodatabase features to their ArcGIS online subscription offering they will continue to lose people to open source.